# Computer Password

Tags: combinatorics

If you need to enter password for someone's computer.
The password contains six characters exactly ( four digits and two capital letters).
How many passwords are there?
The four digits in any order.
Also if digits in specific order.?

Hint: around one hundred millions.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: try simple example, lets say you have to enter 2 charactert (1 digit and 1 letter), how many ways are there?

Comment: For letter : 26x26 probabilities

Comment: if you use only letters yes, but if you include digits then you get much bigger number. Plus your answer is for the case when you enter in specific order. when order doesn't matter, then entering $ab$ is equal to entering $ba$, so you need to exclude these options

Comment: For digits : 10^4

Comment: I know its big.

Comment: I need the probabilities for the pass if digits in order.

Comment: I suggest you to edit your question, don't write things like $bonus$ question, peope are not dying to solve the questions. Please add your attempts and see if anyone will add to your attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 26 capital letters, and you need two. There are $26^2$ ways to arrange this. Similarly, there are 10 one-digit integers of which four have to be ordered. There are $10^4$ ways to do this.

But we are not done. Since passwords have to be in order, we have to find the number of arrangements we can order 2 letters and 4 numbers. Luckily, this is pretty easy and we can just do it in $\binom{2+4}{2}$ = $\binom{6}{2}$ = $15$ ways.

Multiply everything up ($26^2, 10^4, \text { and } 15)$ to get your answer. You can leave it in exponential form, but when calculated it equals 101,400,000. Around 100M, as expected!

-FruDe

Comment: That is totally correct.

Comment: What if digits are in decreasing/ascending order??

Comment: Awaiting users to answer the 2nd part of the Q.